# Logcat : column _id does not exist (SQL related)

Tags: android, sql, database, cursor, logcat

I am currently experiencing a very annoying problem with my application : the goal is to read in a listview different information from a database depending on the button the user is clicking. Unfortunately, my application always crashes and I couldn't find a working solution among similar questions on stackoverflow (tried changes of version of database, adding some lines about the cursor, etc.).

Here is the relevant part of my code:

**A. DatabaseAdapter class :**

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Restaurants";

public static final String COL_CAT1 = "cat1";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String COL_CAT2 = "cat2";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_COMMENTS = "comments";

private Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private Cursor c;

// Constructor
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.myContext = context;

}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(myContext);
    // TODO: or maybe?
    // database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        dbHelper.createDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (c != null) {   
        c.close();
    }
    try {
        dbHelper.close();
        myDatabase.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public Cursor findNameInTable(int myVariable) {
    c = myDatabase
            .query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COL_NAME , COL_COMMENTS }, 
                    COL_CAT1+"=?",
                    new String[] { Integer.toString(myVariable) }, null,
                    null, null);
    return c;
}
```

}

**B. ResultListViewActivity (the results are supposed to be displayed via this activity in a ListView):**

```
public class ResultListViewActivity extends Activity {

private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
private DatabaseAdapter dbHelper;
ListView listview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_list_view);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this); // open() method is in DatabaseAdapter

    dbHelper.open();


    displayListView();
}

private void displayListView() {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int myVariable = bundle.getInt("myVariable");

    Cursor c = dbHelper.findNameInTable(myVariable);
    // the desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.COL_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_COMMENTS, };
    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.comments, };
    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    // as well as the layout information
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c,
            columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

**Picture of my database : as you can see, there is actually an _id column:**
[image]

And finally, a picture of my logcat in case of:
[image]

If you want to see some other part of my code, just let me know. Thanks in advance for any kind of help !

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14617726/1365960).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ListView needs a _id column in it's selection query.you have to include an _id column to your List query

change your query to :

```
c = myDatabase
        .query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,COL_NAME , COL_COMMENTS }, 
                COL_CAT1+"=?",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(myVariable) }, null,
                null, null);
```